# What would cause directories in Linux to be spontaneously overwritten by a previous version

Tags: linux, filesystems, data-recovery

*Edited to add correct ESXi version*

I am running into a very odd issue that is making me feel like an idiot, although I'm sure it has some simple explanation that I'm hoping one of you fine folks can point me toward.

We are running a Linux server, Centos 7.9.2009 with all the latest updates as a LAMP server on a virtual machine, load balancing is enabled. VSphere, ESXi 6.5.0. The server is locked down well and is behind commercial grade firewalls. The servers are very high end. My teammate and I use the virtual Linux machine for test development of individual code projects and quick scripts. We connect from inside the firewall via SSH to update files for testing. Generally files are uploaded using winSCP. We keep backups of important projects in a versioning tool on a separate server.

The general gist of the issue is that 5 times now in the last 3 years my teammate and I have had either single files or directories replaced, seemingly spontaneously on the server, with previous versions. Even the last updated / modified date is reverted along with all permissions etc.

In each case code that had been in place, was suddenly just gone overnight, replaced with older versions of the file. In some cases the whole directory EXCLUDING sub directories was replaced with older versions of the files in it. This is not, as far as I can tell, a case of overwriting by the end user as all modified dates were also reverted.

Code that was active in memory for the files in question was still running fine and was still up to date, restarting it however resulted of course in the previous version getting loaded and errors being thrown.

The latest incident is perl code I finished yesterday at the end of the day (1/10 Monday), saved, and successfully tested between 5 and 6pm. This morning however the code, modified dates and all showed 1/3 (the previous Monday) as the latest modified date. The logs and other files still showed 1/10 and the database and logs had data that only existed in the new version.

When the nightly full server backup (run between 12pm and 1am last night 1/10-1/11) was checked the files in question had modified dates of 1/7 (Friday) and the logs and sub directories showed 1/10... This means the backup showed files 4 days newer than the ones that had replaced the latest, but did not have the latest changes saved the night before. This means the rollback had to have occurred prior to last night's nightly backup but after my last saved changes.

I can typically restore my work from versioning when this happens, and this is just test code, but my bigger concern is how in the world this could happen??

Some background... we do server level backups nightly on the test server. Full backups including file level on the rest of the environment. I don't believe the issue can be due to a restore from backups as only the directory in question was reverted but a sub directory in that directory was still current and even had logs from last night's testing, no other files on the server that we could identify had been overwritten, and we only have the ability to extract files by mounting as a virtual device or by doing a full restore. Furthermore no restores were known to have run, the backup manager shows no restores, and the system admin confirms that no restores were run in any of the cases, and as noted, other files and sub-directories still had the correct modified dates and logs.

So, I am stumped and would welcome any suggestions anybody might have be it human error, or some weird auto-recovery or whatever. If I hadn't seen this happen now 5 times, in 3 years I would be convinced I was nuts, but now I've seen it, my teammate has seen it, and the system Admin was able to verify it using backups.

Thank you all and please let me know if I failed to provide any useful details or can clarify anything.

Comment: if its a virtual machine, I would suspect snapshot revert or bad usage at the virtualization level, or storage level. for exemple if your virtualization had an attempt to move your VM (because of load or whatever) from one node to another, but failed an reverted... just an experience from mines.

Comment: It is a virtual machine, and does have load balancing. I wondered about that as well... you mention that is from an experience of yours, have you ever seen something load balance, fail, revert, and in doing so lose or revert stuff? That would obviously be a bug, but would make sense to me.

Comment: yes I did. what is your virtualization hypervisor (and storage layers) ?

Comment: Interesting, we are running VMware ESXi, 6.5.0, VMFS 6. Thank you!

Comment: Is it a single ESXi server or one of a cluster? If part of a cluster, ask your sysadmin team to check for any migration at all between the latest time of known good to the earliest time of known bad

Comment: Yes, it is a cluster. I asked him to check and am waiting to hear back from him. I'll update this as soon as I hear from him. Thank you all for the pointers!

Comment: I did speak with the lead sysadmin and he verified that while it is a cluster and is set to migrate under load etc, there was no migration seen during that time.